# Angular CLI phonegap plugins

Tags: angular, cordova, angular-cli, phonegap

I am new to phonegap and also new to angluar cli, so please assume I know nothing and provide full examples with your answers. How do you go about using phonegap plugins in an Angular 5 project?

I've made an angular website that uses a .net core web api backend and it works in phonegap - however I need to use a plugin, specifically FileWriter I believe. One of the things my app will need to do is generate a PDF server side and pass that back to the client side as a file - which will need to be saved to the phone/open on the phone. My webapi method returns a FileContentResult. In the angular ts file for that page I was using an npm library called filesaver, and on successful request to get said pdf file, I would stick the returned result into a blob and use the filesaver saveAs method to pop up a file save dialog... this works great on a desktop web browser, but when I run this in phonegap dev app on my android phone it doesn't work.

So after some digging around I think I need to use one of the phonegap plugins which are injected at runtime.

My problem is that I've no idea how to do that. All of the plugins I've used so far in my angular application have been downloaded using npm, then there is a physical library I can reference in the ts files... for example:

```
import { DataService } from '../shared/dataService'
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver'
...
```

then when I call my web api method I can reference saveAs like so:

```
this.data.generatePdf(myParam).subscribe(data => {
let fileName = "portfolioValuation.pdf";
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
saveAs(blob, fileName);
}
```

I assume the imports know about these methods and libraries because they are in the node_modules folder - and I can't remember, but I assume I told angular about the node_module folder at some point - or it is just inbuilt into angular because you install it using npm??

Anyway, the phonegap plugins seem to generate at runtime and therefore I don't have them in the node_modules folder. instead they are in the plugins folder of my phonegap project folder, and therefore I can't reference them - then angular doesn't know about them - so it underlines it in red and I assume it won't build.

So how do I go about using these phonegap plugins in my ts files? specifically the file writer - also since as I'm talking about the file writer is this the plugin I need in order to save my returned file on to the phone? All I want is to allow a mobile user to click a button and be able to open the returned pdf.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this exact approach to work, so I've worked around the problem. I may have been close with my initial attempts, so I will share that in case it is of help - but I will also share my work around.

So my .net core web api method was returning a File content result like so:

```
return File(pdfBuffer, "application/pdf", fileName);
```

pdfBuffer is a byte[], followed by MIME type and filename.

In my dataService ts file in angular I was calling this method like so:

```
public generatePdf(param1) {
    let body = {
        "param1": param1
    };

    let pdfOptions = new RequestOptions();
    pdfOptions.headers = this.options.headers;
    pdfOptions.responseType = ResponseContentType.Blob;

    return this.http.post("https://myWebsite/api/GeneratePdf", body, pdfOptions)
        .map((res: Response) => res.blob());
}
```

I've renamed variables and method names etc, but you can see I've specified the response type to be blob and mapped the response as such. I've also copied the header from a generic header I'm using that contains an authentication token

After I call this in the page ts file, I subscribe and this is where I started getting problems...

To get cordova to pick up in my ts files I've added the following to my tsconfig.json file at the root of the project:

```
"types": [
  "cordova",
  "cordova-plugin-file"
],
```

I also used npm to install phonegap and cordova libraries into my project.

In the page's ts file I added the following variables under my imports so I could pick up the injected cordova libraries:

```
declare var window: any;
declare var LocalFileSystem: any;
declare var device: any;
var storageLocation = "";
declare var cordova: any;
```

Then this method to save or show the blob as a pdf:

```
public generatePdf() {
    let param1= param1Logic;
    $("#waitingAnimation").show();

    this.data.generatePdf(param1).subscribe(data => {
        let fileName = "myDocument.pdf";
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        $("#waitingAnimation").hide();

        //I tried to just open the pdf on the device like so... just get a blank white page on phonegap
        //var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        //window.open(fileURL); // if you want to open it in new tab 


        switch (device.platform) {

            case "Android":
                storageLocation = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/';
                break;
            case "iOS":
                storageLocation = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
                break;

        }

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

            console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
            let parentEntry = storageLocation + "Download/" + fileName;
            fs.root.getFile(parentEntry, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                    console.log('create writer');

                    fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                        console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
                    };

                    fileWriter.write(blob);
                });

            }, null);

        }, null);

    });
}
```

This might not be the exact code - I did a lot of tinkering without saving to a repository - so I've just put this together roughly from the comments I left in my code. I don't get any console errors - It just doesn't do anything.

I think it has something to do with the response being a blob, and something to do with whitelists. I started to read up on it and found it had security implications and nowhere could I find anything describing how to make it safe so at this point I started to think of other solutions.

So my work around...

I thought I'd try getting a pdf from another old aspx website that just requires a simple get request to this ashx page, which just returns a pdf file with pdf MIME type. I could call this in angular and get it to open the pdf in a browser using the following code:

```
window.open("https://myWebsite.ashx?fileName=" + fileName, '_system', 'location=no');
```

So what I did was change my Web API to work around this.

Instead of using a post to respond back with a blob, instead that post to the server creates a pdf, which gets stored in a temporary directory on the server - this post method responds with some JSON with the filename.

I then created another Web API method what takes a get request with the filename as a parameter (query string), this looks for that temporary file (I know the server location, and just append the filename provided) - if the file exists I respond with a FileContentResult like before and delete the file from temporary storage. Like so:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [DeleteFileAttribute]
    public IActionResult Get(string fileName)
    {
        var tempPath = $"serverLocationGoesHere/{fileName}";
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempPath);
        return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf", fileName);
    }
```

The DeleteFileAttribute is a custom attribute I made to delete the file.

So now in my dataService ts file I call the initial GeneratePdf post method to generate the pdf:

```
public generatePdf(param1) {
    let body = {
        "param1": param1
    };

    return this.http.post("https://myWebSite/api/GeneratePdf", body, this.options)
        .map((res: Response) => {
            return res.json();
        });
}
```

As you can see this just returns JSON...

so in my page ts file all I need to do is:

```
public generatePdf() {
    let param1 = param1Logic;
    $("#waitingAnimation").show();

    this.data.generatePdf(param1).subscribe(data => {
        let fileName = data.fileName;
        $("#waitingAnimation").hide();
        window.open("https://myWebsSite/api/DownloadFile?fileName=" + fileName, '_system', 'location=no');

}
```

And now I can open server generated PDFs in my phonegap application - albeit not in the way I intended. I'm sure there are better ways to open the Pdf also using some library - but Hopefully there is something useful to someone in here!